# Cancel a query in Breeze JS

Tags: javascript, breeze, q

Is there some way to cancel a query I'm running in BreeseJS. I don't really care if the query runs server side, but it would be nice if I could just call a method or something to make sure that it doesn't call the method I have assigned to the promise using *then*. So let's say that my code looks something like

```
var promise = manager.executeQuery(myFavouriteQuery);
promise.then(myFavouriteFunction);
```

Is there something I can do with the promise later so that it won't call the function I gave it in *then*.

Comment: Are you trying to stop the query as it is running or catch the promise and then decide whether to hit the function after the promise is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update 16 May 2014

You can set HTTP-level timeout and cancellation with the AJAX Adapter's `requestInterceptor` as of v.1.4.12. See the documentation, ["Controlling AJAX calls"](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/controlling-ajax).

## Original answer

Breeze uses Q for it's promises support.  There has been some discussion on the concept of cancellable promises here: [Q Cancellation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/issues/64).  When Q supports this, then Breeze will as well.